# Passing class field to member function

Tags: c++, c++11, methods

I have a class which has a few large fields (say, some big matrices) and has member functions to compute these matrices (the actual number of the matrices is bigger, of course)

```
class MyClass  {
protected:
    MatrixType m_11, m_12;
public:
    void compute_m_11(double x);
    void compute_m_12(double x);
}
```

Now, the computation code is very similar, and the most complex part is correct indexing of the matrix elements (which is the same for all the matrices involved). So I was thinking about splitting the indexing and the computation into separate functions: a `compute_matrix` function which will perform the indexing and call a `compute_element` function for each set of indexes in the matrix. This would greatly improve code readability and ease debugging.

So the `compute_matrix` function would take a `MatrixType` reference to the class field which I need to fill in and a `std::function` which would perform the actual computation. I obviously want to avoid writing anything that will involve additional copying of the matrices, since they can be quite large.

So, the questions are:

1. Is it legal/efficient to pass a reference to a class field to a class member function?
2. If so, do I need to use `std::bind` to pass the computation member functions? The `compute_elements` functions need to access some other fields of `MyClass`.

This is what I have in mind:

```
class MyClass  {
protected:
    MatrixType m_11, m_12;
    double compute_elements_m11(int i, int j, double x);
    double compute_elements_m12(int i, int j, double x);
    void compute_matrix(MatrixType &m, double x, std::function<double(int, int, double) > f);
public:
    void compute_m_11(double x) {compute_matrix(m_11, x, compute_elements_m11);};
    void compute_m_12(double x) {compute_matrix(m_12, x, compute_elements_m12);};
}
```

Comment: How the latter "greatly improves code readability and ease(s) debugging" compared to the former utterly escapes me, but I leave that as a matter of opinion, I suppose. The legality question (1) is easily settled by simply *trying* it. And (2) once in the body of `compute_elements_xxx` (however you get there, `bind` or otherwise), you have access to the object (you better; you're in one of its member functions, `this` is already established), so you had better have said-access or something went horribly wrong.

Comment: Readability and ease of debugging are improved since the matrix has to be traversed in a complex way, and decoupling that and the computation will allow to write the code that walks around the matrix elements only once. And the computation code itself is quite short - without the indexing part it will be quite easy to check for correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is legal (and not that uncommon) to pass a member reference, but your function type is wrong.
You could use `std::bind`, or you could use a plain pointer-to-member:

```
class MyClass  {
protected:
    MatrixType m_11, m_12;
    double compute_elements_m11(int i, int j, double x);
    double compute_elements_m12(int i, int j, double x);
    void compute_matrix(MatrixType &m, double x, double (MyClass::*f) (int, int, double);
public:
    void compute_m_11(double x) {compute_matrix(m_11, x, &MyClass::compute_elements_m11);};
    void compute_m_12(double x) {compute_matrix(m_12, x, &MyClass::compute_elements_m12);};
};
```

`std::bind` and `std::function` gives a more flexible implementation though.

Comment: I think you mean `MyClass::` not `MatrixType::` in the function signatures

Comment: The fun part is where you have to call the function pointer in your compute_matrix implementation. because compute_elements_m1[1/2] is not static, you have to point to your current object. So e.g. `(this->*f)(1, 2, x)`

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's not uncommon to pass a class attribute to an internal member function and you can also use `std:bind` to call the member function, but the question is do you really need that or can you just use a simple "if" or something similar to decide what to use? I'd say it depends on how many choices your code path has to decide that better.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you pass a reference to a class field to a class member function? A better solution would be to implement a get method and use that in the `compute_matrix` function. Your class will then look something like this:

```
class MyClass  {
protected:
    MatrixType m_11, m_12;
    double compute_elements_m11(int i, int j, double x);
    double compute_elements_m12(int i, int j, double x);
    void compute_matrix(double x, std::function<double(int, int, double) > f);
public:
    void compute_m_11(double x) {compute_matrix(x, compute_elements_m11);};
    void compute_m_12(double x) {compute_matrix(x, compute_elements_m12);};

    MatrixType& getMatrixType_11( return m_11 );
    MatrixType& getMatrixType_12( return m_12 );

}
```

Comment: "[...] and use that in the member function". In which member function do you mean? It's `compute_matrix()` that needs to know whether to read `m_11` or `m_12`. Just adding some extra helper functions is not going to help.